# Get filtered data in component table after executing the filter function on dataSource in ant design

Tags: reactjs, antd

When useing the Table component in Ant-desigin, i want to get the filterd data in table after executing the filter function on the dataSource, but i cannot find the way to get it. There is a function called onChange which can only get the filter conditions which can not get the filtered data.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: I'm not sure why posting code would actually help here. I'm looking for a way to do the same.

You can define filters and how they work in the component to make filtering easy, but what Jochen is asking (and I'm wondering too) is, how to get the filtered data out of the `<Table>`. 

For example: Let's say I have an `<Table>` with a `dataSource` array of 50 objects, after setting my filters, the `<Table>` only shows 20 objects. Now I'd like an array of these 20 objects to use somewhere else.

Answer (score 5):

You can easily add `onChange` attribute inside `<Table/>`. Create a function with 4 params: `pagination, filters, sorter, extra` and the data you're looking for is `extra.currentDataSource`.

```js
onChange={
     (pagination, filters, sorter, extra) => {
          console.log(extra.currentDataSource)
     } 
}
```

Comment: This answer should be marked as accepted. This helped me figure out what I was missing.

Answer (score 4):

Add **onChange** function to Table(sample code is ts, if you are using js, do a little adjustment. And you can check the debug result: total dataSource size is 54, filtered dataSource size is 40, pagination doesn't impact the result

```js
  handleChange = (pagination: any, filters: any, sorter: any, extra: { currentDataSource: Array<any>[] }) => {
    console.log('Various parameters', extra.currentDataSource);
    this.setState({
      filteredInfo: extra['currentDataSource']
    });
  }

  renderTable = (columns: Array<object>, dataSource: Array<any>) => {
    return (
      <Table
        dataSource={dataSource}
        columns={columns}
        expandedRowRender={(record) => (<Markdown source={record['description']} className="brz-mentor-markdown" />)}
        onChange={this.handleChange as any}
      />
    )
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I kinda found a way. The props `title` and `footer` on the `<Table />` component take a function which does provide the filtered data.

```
<Table
  footer={currentPageData => {
    console.log(currentPageData); // <-- This is an array of the filtered dataSource.
    return null;
  }}
/>
```

Comment: It seems that by this way, the ```currentPageData``` is the data in current page, and when the filterd data covers several pages, this method may not works. So if i want to get all the filterd data no matter how many pages it covers, which way can i do?Thx

Answer (score 1):

One case, the onChange solution can't work.

1. Set a filter on table, onChange will be called, so you can get the correct count of filtered rows.
2. Reload the table with data from some kind of ajax calling, and because the fitler is still there, so the data will be filtered. But onChange is not called, so no chance to get the correct count after table reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

We found a solution for this. It is very much a hack, but appears to work. filterDropdown has callback functions so you can write your own popup UI for filters. If we add a hidden filter to a column and save the callbacks after the Table component is loaded, we can call them to trigger a call to onChange.

You need a column where you don't need a filter interface. For example, we have an "Action" column with buttons in it, so we put the hidden filter there.

There is a full working example here https://codesandbox.io/s/customized-filter-panel-antd-5-9-4-forked-6tfqtw?file=/demo.tsx:5542-5597

This issue is also tracked in GitHub here https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/24022

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import {Table} from 'antd'

const TableWithRestoredState = () => {
 // used to track if the Table has loaded and trigger a re-render
 const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false)

// used to store a ref to the callback from antd
  const triggerDataRef = React.useRef<() => void | void>(null)

// count the renders so we only do this once
  const renderTimesRef = React.useRef<number>(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (renderTimesRef.current === 1 && triggerDataRef.current) {
      triggerDataRef.current()
    }
    renderTimesRef.current += 1
  }, [loaded])

  const columns  = [
    {
      title: "My Column",
      filterDropdown: ({ setSelectedKeys, confirm }) => {
        if (!triggerDataRef.current) {
          triggerDataRef.current = () => {
            setSelectedKeys(["fake key"])
            confirm()
          };
          setLoaded(true)
        }
        return <div></div>
      },
      onFilter: (value, record) => {
        return true; // needed so no rows are actually filtered by our fake filter
      },
      filterIcon: () => {
        return <div></div>
      }
    }
   ]

// filtered data will store a local copy of the sorted or filtered data from the antd Table
 const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([])

const handleChange = (pagination, filters, sorter, extra) => {
    if (extra.action === "filter" || extra.action === "sort") {
      setFilteredData(extra.currentDataSource)
    }
  }

 return <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} onChange={handleChange} />
}
```